# I buy a domain in Azure portal, then how to veryfy domain ownership in Google Webmaster tool?

Tags: azure, dns

Google demand site ownership in Google webmastertool.

But I can't find Azure as a Domain Provider in Google webmastertool.

Does someone know how to verify Azure provided domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the "Alternate Methods" tab in Webmaster Tools:
[image]